# CakePHP site upgrade from 1.3.3 to 2.3.2

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, upgrade, cakephp-2.3

**Update:**

Found out via `cake/VERSION.txt` that it's actually 1.3.3

---

I have website running on cakePHP v 0.2.9 built in 2008. but now in PHP 5 some functions and functionality are deprecated. And my site stopped running.

Can anyone please show me better and easy way I can upgrade my cakePHP version without affecting my site and make it up running.

header of my index.php on root folder is as below (for you guys to better understanding of my site's cakephp version)

```
/**    
 * Requests collector.    
 *    
 *  This file collects requests if:    
 *  - no mod_rewrite is avilable or .htaccess files are not supported    
 *  -/public is not set as a web root.    
 *    
 * PHP versions 4 and 5    
 *    
 * CakePHP(tm) : Rapid Development Framework (http://www.cakephp.org)    
 * Copyright 2005-2008, Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://www.cakefoundation.org)    
 *    
 * Licensed under The MIT License    
 * Redistributions of files must retain the above copyright notice.    
 *    
 * @filesource    
 * @copyright     Copyright 2005-2008, Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://www.cakefoundation.org)    
 * @link          http://www.cakefoundation.org/projects/info/cakephp CakePHP(tm) Project    
 * @package       cake    
 * @since         CakePHP(tm) v 0.2.9    
 * @version       $Revision: 7945 $    
 * @modifiedby    $LastChangedBy: gwoo $    
 * @lastmodified  $Date: 2008-12-18 20:16:01 -0600 (Thu, 18 Dec 2008) $    
 * @license       http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php The MIT License    
 */    
/**
```

Comment: 0.2.9? Wow. It's probably changed so much that you just have to go through it line by line, or rewrite it altogether.

Comment: Also note that the number in the index.php file does not necessarily mean that your version is 0.2.9. It just says that the requests collector has been included in CakePHP since version 0.2.9. (It is, in fact, pretty unlikely that you have 0.2.9.)

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but here's a question I asked awhile ago about upgrading versions of Cake:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6279340/migrating-from-cake-1-3-to-2-0-and-beyond-migrate-existing-or-only-use-for-ne

Comment: Why on earth are you using such an old version of a WEB(!!!) framework? Don't mind security issues?

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

[CakePHP Migration guide from 1.3 - 2.0](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-0-migration-guide.html)

(You'll then see the rest of the migration guides for 2.1, 2.2...etc on the left rail)

---

You might want to just install the latest CakePHP fresh, then copy over all YOUR files (controllers, models, views, plugins, webroot files (css, js..etc) to it and test/fix from there.  If nothing else, the most recent CakePHP will give you better/more specific error reporting, so hopefully you can just fix one error at a time until there aren't any left.

The other option would be to go through all the migration notes and change line-by-line, but going from 0.2.9 .... bottom line, there is likely no easy way.

(I hope for your sake the commenters are right that you have 1.3 or something instead.)

Comment: My site is showing nothing, just a balnk white page. I have tried to replace cake folder with late version cake folder. now it is showing me header images of my current site but again else page is blank.

Comment: How can I check my correct cakePHP version of site?
How can I go line-by-line, please guide?

Comment: @Paks - you're going to have to start debugging then.  Make sure `debug` is set to 2 (`app/core/config.php`), and start debugging stuff - start in the AppController and work your way down.

Comment: "To see your version, in the cake/VERSION.txt file, look at the very last line. It's easy to miss, but it should just be a number, e.g. 1.3.8."  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6279340/migrating-from-cake-1-3-to-2-0-and-beyond-migrate-existing-or-only-use-for-ne

Comment: @Juhana, @ Dave - You are right, according to VERSION.txt my version is 1.3.3

Comment: Cool - updated answer.  But after you're done following the migration guides, if you're still having problems, do the debugging like mentioned above in comments.

Comment: Thanks Dave let me go through migration guide. If there will be any prob, I will get back to this post again.

Comment: My server having PHP-4.4.9 and MySql-5.0.51a. So to which version of cakePHP should I upgrade from?

Comment: @Paks - please feel free to continue this discussion in chat or ask another question about which CakePHP version depending on server...etc.